# How to handle null for a allow-null datetime field (DB) in our program?

Tags: c#, datetime, null

How could we handle null for a datetime field (got from SQL Server) in our program in c#?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are 3 common approaches here;

- if you are talking about `object` (perhaps as you fetch it from a data-reader), then `DBNull.Value` can represent null. I don't tend to let this out of the data-layer, though
- due to .NET 1.1 history, `DateTime.MinValue` is commonly interpreted as `null`; a magic number, maybe - but it works and is supported by most data-binding etc
- in .NET 2.0, `Nullable<T>` means you can use `DateTime?` - i.e. a nullable-of-DateTime; just use `DateTime?` where-ever you mean a `DateTime` that can be null, and you can give it a value of `null` or a valid `DateTime`.

Some other thoughts on data-access and nulls:

- when passing to a `SqlCommand` you *must* use `DBNull.Value`, not `null` - see below
- when reading from a data-reader, I tend to check `reader.IsDbNull(ordinal)`

command stuff (with `Nullable<T>` as the example):

```
param.Value = when.HasValue ? (object)when.Value : DBNull.Value;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `DateTime?`

What problem are you having, specifically?

-- Edit

Just so it's clear, that's a `Nullable` DateTime object, not a question :)

```
DateTime? t = null;
```

-- Edit

Responding to comment, check it like so:

```
DateTime? theTime;

if( table["TheColumn"] == DBNull.Value ){
    theTime = null;
} else {
    theTime = (DateTime) table["TheColumn"];
}
```

Comment: I can not cast object (a column of DataRow) to DateTime .

Comment: Responded via edit. You just need to check if it is equal to `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: Okay ... You may like to post how you've solved it and mark it as accepted, so it helps anyone else who searches.